# How to configure this Android project from Github?

Tags: android, git, github, android-gradle-plugin

The project is on git at following address: https://github.com/ambikab/CarPool

I am new to android so please help me to configure this in android studio.

Comment: What is the issue, you are facing?

Comment: I just added the project in android studio. when i was adding it to android studio the studio has not asked me to build gradle. I am seeing lot of redness in project which is the sign of errors.

Comment: Android Studio has an 'check out project from version control' , have you tried that? there is a built in feature for downloading and importing a github project, how did you 'add' the project to Android Studio?

Comment: If you try it and help me out how i can configure it. i will be thankful to you

Comment: i have not checked because this project is not on my git account this is on someone else account. so how can i download and configure it directly in studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the 'download as zip' to get the files you need from the github page (if you don't know how to use git)

Then in Android Studio's "welcome to android studio" prompt, click on and use the "import project (Eclipse,...)" because this is an eclipse project, that needs to be converted to use gradle.

Comment: followed your instructions and the project is imported and giving the following error
Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-19' in: C:\Users\Tanveer1941\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>

Comment: that means you don't have the android 19 API installed on your system. You have to 1) install it 2) change the `compileSdkVersion` version inside the build.grade within the 'app' module

Comment: Configured with your answer help but not able to understand whats going on in code.

Comment: i m not able to login or sign up in the application.

Comment: Well that is a separate issue than 'getting it configured into Android Studio', so please make a new question about any specific questions you have. Good Luck